# 'toLowerCase' of undefined in Angular 7 http post

Tags: angular

I've read a few forums and can't seem to find this issue.

I have an auth service that should respond with a token.

This is my auth Service call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    baseUrl: 'https://api.website.com/login/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(model: any) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, model)
            .pipe(
                map(data => data)
            );
    }
}
```

in my login component, I have the following call:

```
login() {
    this.auth.login(this.model)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

I'm receiving the following error in the console -

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined   at
> HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept
> (http.js:1719)   at
> HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle
> (http.js:1135)   at
> HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle
> (http.js:1770)   at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:975)   at
> MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
> (mergeMap.js:61)   at
> MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next
> (mergeMap.js:51)   at
> MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
> (Subscriber.js:54) at Observable._subscribe (scalar.js:5)   at
> Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
> (Observable.js:43)   at
> Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
> (Observable.js:29)

I don't have any interceptors, and am not sure where this is all coming from. Any help?

Comment: I think this is likely to do with the endpoint returning nothing, error is then probably caused by trying to pipe() and map() undefined. Can you get a response from the api in postman?

Comment: I don't think so because the network never even makes a call to that url. It's empty.

Comment: change `baseUrl: 'https://api.website.com/login/';` to `baseUrl = 'https://api.website.com/login/';`

Comment: duh. thanks! Stupid mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964095/angular-6-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 baseUrl: 'https://api.website.com/login/';
```

to

```
 baseUrl= 'https://api.website.com/login/';
```